# In Sublime Text 3, how do you enable Autocompletion of HTML in JSX

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext3, jsx

In Sublime Text 3, I have the `Babel` package for syntax highlighting of HTML code in JSX.

However the HTML code does not have auto-completion, such as those wrapped inside the `render()` block. How can we enable auto-completion for the HTML codes?

Answer (score 8):

You need the Emmet plug-in to have autocompletition within JSX components.

Use your package controller to install Emmet. Among other Emmet capabilities, just after writing the name of a tag, by pressing `Ctrl+E` it will be transformed into a opening-closing tag pair. If you want to use the `Tab` button, you'll need to modify the basic Emmet configuration by adding into Package Settings -> Emmet -> Key Bindings (User) a JSON doc like:

```
[
    {
        keys: ["tab"],
        command: "expand_abbreviation_by_tab",
        context: [
            {
                operand: "source.js",
                operator: "equal",
                match_all: true,
                key: "selector",
            },
            { match_all: true, key: "selection_empty" },
            {
                operator: "equal",
                operand: false,
                match_all: true,
                key: "has_next_field",
            },
            {
                operand: false,
                operator: "equal",
                match_all: true,
                key: "auto_complete_visible",
            },
            { match_all: true, key: "is_abbreviation" },
        ],
    },
];
```

The `Tab` autocompletition is not allowed by default to avoid conflicts with inner Sublime Text features, but this script will make Emmet aware of this and will allow autocompletition within the scope of a JSX file

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I installed Emmet. It is working well outside JSX in a plain HTML file, but in JSX it is not working.

Comment: Ctrl + e is so close to Ctrl + w and if that happens, you are screwed as project closes

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to answer as it depends a lot of your Sublime Text plugins.

If you are using Babel as formatting for JS and a HTML package such as Emmet, you should be fine. In some situation the "tab" may not work, but Emmet CTRL+e will still expand any partial tag, even using properly "className" instead of class.

Comment: Babel has nothing to do with HTML autocomplete. It is not possible, fyi